# How can I test sequence of function calls by Sinon.js?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, sinon

How can I test sequence of function calls by Sinon.js?

For example i have three (3) handlers in object, and want define sequence of handler calls. Is there any possibilities for this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

http://sinonjs.org/docs/

*sinon.assert.callOrder(spy1, spy2, ...)*

Passes if the provided spies where called in the specified order.

Comment: Using [Function.prototype.apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), you can call it with an array of spies like this: `sinon.assert.callOrder.apply(sinon.assert, [spy1, spy2, spy3]);`

Comment: What about if I have one spy, and I want to assert that it was called first with an arg of 1 and second with an arg of 2?

Comment: It looks like `callOrder` has been removed. The current approach is to use [`calledBefore`](http://sinonjs.org/releases/v4.1.2/spies/#spycalledbeforeanotherspy) and the related methods.

Answer (score 3):

For people who run into this looking for a way to define stubs with a specified behaviour on a call sequence. There is no direct way (as far as I've seen) to say: "This stub will be called `X` times, on the 1st call it will take parameter `a` and return `b` on the 2nd call it will take parameter  `c` and return `d` ..." and so on.

The closest I found to this behaviour is:

```
  const expectation = sinon.stub()
            .exactly(N)
            .onCall(0)
            .returns(b)
            .onCall(1)
            .returns(d)
            // ...
            ;
   // Test that will end up calling the stub
   // expectation.callCount should be N
   // expectation.getCalls().map(call => call.args) should be [ a, b, ... ]
```

This way we can return specific values on each call in the sequence and then assert that the calls were made with the parameters we expected.

Answer (score 0):

As Gajus mentioned `callOrder()` is no longer available and you can use `callBefore()`, `calledAfter()`, `calledImmediatelyBefore()` and `calledImmediatelyAfter()`.

I found most convenient to assert sequential calls of one spy by getting all calls using  `spy.getCalls()` and do `assert.deepEqual()` for call arguments.

Example - Assert order of `console.log()` calls.

```
// func to test
function testee() {
  console.log(`a`)
  console.log(`b`)
  console.log(`c`)
}
```

In your test case

```
const expected = [`a`, `b`, `c`]
const consoleSpy = spy(console, 'log')

testee()

const result = consoleSpy.getCalls().map(({ args }) => args[0])

assert.deepEqual(result, expected)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also a sinon-chai plugin.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/sinon-chai-in-order

```
expect(spy).inOrder.to.have.been.calledWith(1)
                   .subsequently.calledWith(2)
                   .subsequently.calledWith(3);
```